# TSQL Insert missing dates and increments

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a table (StatDays) that contains a count of days (DaysInStatus) that an order was in a particular status. There is an entry for each day the order remained in that status, except for Sundays when there was no process to write to this table. In that case, the order would appear again on Monday, with DaysInStatus advanced two days.

My problem is how to populate the missing Sunday values. (I am assuming that if an order has a Saturday entry but no Monday entry, that Saturday is the last desired data point.)

Example:

```
OrderID StatDate    DaysInStatus
A11111  6/1/2012    20
A11111  6/2/2012    21
A11111  6/4/2012    23
A11111  6/5/2012    24
A11111  6/6/2012    25
A11111  6/7/2012    26
A11111  6/8/2012    27
A11111  6/9/2012    28
A11111  6/11/2012   30
```

Here I would want to insert (or select) into another table all of these values, plus the missing dates 6/3 and 6/10 - where DaysInStatus is advanced to 22 and 29, respectively - and the OrderID.

Also, an OrderID will NOT always appear in this table at DaysInStatus = 1. In can appear at almost any value, and drop out at almost any value.

I have tried generating a dates table, then doing left outer join to StatDays on statDate and StatDate+1, StatDate-1. This works for small recordsets but the actual table has over 100 million records, so this would not work for me.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Will Holidays be also missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will help with any missing days.

```
create table StatDays(OrderID varchar(20),StatDate datetime,
                      DaysInStatus int)   

insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/1/2012',    20)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/2/2012',    21)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/4/2012',    23)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/5/2012',    24)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/6/2012',    25)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/7/2012',    26)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/8/2012',    27)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/9/2012',    28)
insert into statdays values('A11111',  '6/11/2012',   30)
insert into statdays values('A11112',  '6/1/2012',    20)
insert into statdays values('A11112',  '6/2/2012',    21)
insert into statdays values('A11112',  '6/4/2012',    23)
insert into statdays values('A11113',  '6/5/2012',    24)
insert into statdays values('A11113',  '6/6/2012',    25)
insert into statdays values('A11113',  '6/7/2012',    26)
insert into statdays values('A11113',  '6/8/2012',    27)
insert into statdays values('A11113',  '6/9/2012',    28)
insert into statdays values('A11113',  '6/13/2012',   32)







with 
demo_cte as 
(select orderid, min(statdate) Min_Date,max(statdate) Max_Date,
 min(DaysInStatus) Min_Day from StatDays group by orderid

 union all


 select orderid,DateAdd(day,1,Min_Date), Max_date,Min_day+1 from demo_cte
 where DateAdd(day,1,Min_Date)<=Max_date

)
select OrderId,Min_Date Stat_days,Min_Day  from demo_cte
order by orderid
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/361e7/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is your statement

```
INSERT Status
SELECT s1.OrderID
      ,DATEADD(day,1,s1.StatDate)
      ,s1.DaysInStatus+1
FROM Status s1
     INNER JOIN
     Status s2 ON DATEADD(day,2,s1.StatDate)=s2.StatDate
                  AND
                  s1.DaysInStatus+2=s2.DaysInStatus
     LEFT JOIN
     Status s3 ON DATEADD(day,1,s1.StatDate)=s3.StatDate
                  AND
                  s1.DaysInStatus+1=s3.DaysInStatus
WHERE DATENAME(dw,s1.StatDate)='Saturday'
      AND
      s3.OrderID IS NULL
```

You can see an SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2620e/3)